# Disabled button not changing color for DataTrigger in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, binding, styles

I have the below code where I'm trying to change the background color of the button when its disabled. But it still stays at the same background color as it is when its enabled. Its not changing though the button does get disabled. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
 <Button  Content="Install" Command="{Binding InstallCommand}"  Margin="150,30,30,22" Width="118" FontSize="18" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="Segoe UI Light" FontStretch="ExtraExpanded">
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Button">
                        <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True" />
                        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#FF4F4F4F"/>
                        <Setter Property="Template">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                    <Border Name="border" 
                        BorderThickness="1"                                  
                        Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                    </Border>
                                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
                                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Goldenrod"/>
                                        </Trigger>
                                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                </ControlTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding InstallEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Value="">
                                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource windowBGBrushBusinessDateChanged}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>

                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that in your trigger you are not checking the value .Change your trigger as below.

```
 <Style.Triggers>
      <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding InstallEnabled, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" Value="False">
    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />
 <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource windowBGBrushBusinessDateChanged}"/>
 </DataTrigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the disabled button background by changing the control template of button like below,

```
   <Window.Resources>

    <Style x:Key="MyButton2" TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="MediumAquamarine" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="MediumBlue" />

        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="MyContentPresenter"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                          VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                          Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>

        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="DeepPink" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>


</Window.Resources>
<Grid>

    <Button x:Name="disabledButton"
            Width="100"
            Height="100"
            Content="Button State"
            IsEnabled="False"
            Style="{StaticResource MyButton2}" />


</Grid>
```